# kendo ui angular grid - how to leave row when user hits enter key instead of clicking off of row

Tags: kendo-ui-angular2

Ive got a working grid, using in-line editing thanks to this example
https://www.telerik.com/kendo-angular-ui/components/grid/editing/editing-row-click/

What I need to do now, is force the saving upon a user hitting the enter key, instead of clicking away onto another row or away from the current row.  I suppose I could add a "save" button in the header?

Answer (score 1):

You could probably use **cellClose** event in your html `(cellClose)="cellCloseHandler($event)"` -  [API Documentation](https://www.telerik.com/kendo-angular-ui/components/grid/api/GridComponent/)

You could then write your own code (in typescript) in `cellCloseHandler()` to modify and save the updated items accordingly.

From Kendo UI for Angular Documentation:
[In-Cell Editing](https://www.telerik.com/kendo-angular-ui/components/grid/editing/in-cell-editing/#toc-basic-concepts)

You could capture the Enter key hits and force executing `cellCloseHandler()` like that:

```
@HostListener('keydown', ['$event'])
public keydown(event: any): void {
  console.log("keydown event", event);
  if (event.keyCode === 13) {
        this.cellCloseHandler();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Similar to Giannis answer but with small modifications:

- Add keydown event to kendo-grid tag.
- Call grid.closeCell() instead of calling the closeHander directly.

Template

```
    <kendo-grid #grid
                [data]="data$ | async"
                (cellClose)="cellCloseHandler($event)"
                (keydown)="onKeydown(grid, $event)"
    >
```

Class

```
    onKeydown(grid: GridComponent, e: KeyboardEvent) {
        if (e.key === 'Enter') {
            grid.closeCell();
        }
    }

    cellCloseHandler(args: CellCloseEvent) {
        const { formGroup, dataItem } = args;
        // save to backend etc
    }
```

Calling `grid.closeCell();` will make the grid to call `cellCloseHandler`

Answer (score 0):

You dont have to implement a HostListener for Keydown by yourself. If you set the **input navigable** to **true**, the **cellClose event will get triggered** when pressing Enter while editing a cell or row. This way you get the data of the row in your cellCloseHandler aswell for saving it.

```
<kendo-grid [navigable]="true" (cellClose)="cellCloseHandler($event)"></kendo-grid>
```

Comment: What’s the difference between this answer and @Giannis’s from last year?

Comment: @JeremyCaney that you don't have to implement the keydown HostListener. If you set navigable to true Enter trigger the cellClose event with the data of the row by itself.

Comment: Thank you. That would be useful information to edit into your answer so viewers can quickly assess the difference between new answers and established answers. Would you mind doing that?

Comment: `[navigable]` works, but it introduces a strange border around the last selected cell.